# componentWillReceiveProps not being triggered when removing property to object prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Fairly new to react, so really need the communities help,

I have a prop

```
sampleProp = {key:0, value:[]}
```

On a button click I am removing the property 'value' from the prop and I am expecting that will trigger the componentWillReceiveProps react cycle but I is not. The thing is, it is doing fine if I am just removing values from the 'value' property which is an array.

Hopefully someone can help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling this.setState() generally doesn’t trigger componentWillReceiveProps().

You should look into using either [componentWillUpdate()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillupdate) method or just do what you need in the render() method.